# How effective are vocal lifts and how do they work?

Tags: voice

I read that there is a plastic surgery which repairs some of the damage caused by age and misuse of the voice called a vocal lift. What are the effects? How does surgery and speech therapy help someone sing?

Comment: It would be cool if someone can answer who has actually had this procedure and can provide first hand information on it

Comment: Surgery is risky. It seems the results are more positive lately. The type of surgeries called for depend on the need. Why do you think this type will help? More information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

No direct experience, but based on what I heard from others, it's a risky procedure with unpredictable results. There are probably also more than one type of operation, it depends on the conditions and the experience of the doctors. I knew one singer who went for surgery, but only because the alternative was to  stop singing. He was able to sing again after quite some time, but it changed his voice somewhat, and he regrets not having taken a healthier, more correct approach to singing earlier on in his life instead.

Comment: Here's an interview with a voice specialist, (automatic translation from Italian to English with google translate) http://tinyurl.com/voicedoc

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you are seriously considering getting done, your best bet is to call a surgeon and make an appointment to get evaluated.  You are most likely going to get very drastically different answers from users on here.  Only a doctor can tell you what is right for your body.

I would caution you against being hasty about a surgery like this.  Do your research and talk to a doctor.  There aren't a lot of options to reverse the negative effects aging has on the voice, but sometimes, aging isn't a bad thing.  Of course, it's ultimately up to you, but please get a doctor's opinion.  I wish I could give you a first-hand experience story, but I can't.  And I have a feeling that most people on here can't either.

Comment: while valuable advice, this doesn't *really* answer what has been asked...